# JSON code in model / Swift

Tags: json, swift, model

I need to make an Model for that JSON code in Swift, it's Array of Dictionaries. Is it better to use Class or struct ?

```
{
    "User1": {
    "UserID": 1,
    "Username": "username1",
    "Password": "parola1",
    "Email": "email1@email.com",
    "Phone": "088",
    "Posts":   {"Post1": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
        "Post2": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
        "Post3": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}]}
    },

    "User2": {
        "UserID": 2,
        "Username": "username2",
        "Password": "parola2",
        "Email": "email2@email.com",
        "Phone": "089",
        "Posts":   {"Post1": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
            "Post2": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
            "Post3": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}]}
    },
    "User3": {
        "UserID": 3,
        "Username": "username3",
        "Password": "parola3",
        "Email": "email3@email.com",
        "Phone": "090",
        "Posts":   {"Post1": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
            "Post2": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}],
            "Post3": [{"UrlImage": "image"},{"Title": "tekst"},{"description": "info"}]}
    }
}
```

How your struct model will look like ?

Comment: Better to use struct. and just ignore the dictionary key of the parent dictionary

Comment: Btw your json it is not valid. "Phone" = 090 it is not valid. Make sure you post a valid json. "Phone" value should be a string not a number with a leading zero on it

Comment: You just help me to figure out where my problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON already it is easy. You can use [Quicktype](https://swift.quicktype.io/) to autogenerate a struct or class from your JSON. I made slight adaptions to your JSON that it is really an array of dicts. Your model then would probably look like this:

```
typealias Users = [User]

struct User: Codable {
    let password: String
    let posts: Posts
    let email: String
    let phone: String
    let userID: Int
    let username: String
}

struct Posts: Codable {
    let post2: [Post]
    let post1: [Post]
    let post3: [Post]
}

struct Post: Codable {
    let urlImage: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
}
```